# How can I catch ngSantitize errors and display the html as escaped text

Tags: html, angularjs, sanitization, html-sanitizing

We are using AngularJS to try and display user entered content as HTML. Most of the time the users enter valid/safe data which we display correctly using ng-bind-html. Occasionally they enter invalid HTML which I would still like to display as the raw text.

If I use ng-bind-html to attempt to display invalid HTML I get this error:

```
[$sanitize:badparse] The sanitizer was unable to parse the following block of html:
```

I don't want to use trustAsHtml because I don't trust our sanitizer and want to ensure that we do not display unsafe html on the page.

Comment: just use `ng-bind` instead of `ng-bind-html` if you want to display the raw text that was entered.

Comment: ng-bind works great but I want to display the rendered html if it is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a directive to do this. Here is how it is used.

```
<div ng-bind-html-if-safe="SomeHtml"></div>
```

The source for the Directive can be found [here](https://github.com/shaunbowe/ngBindHtmlIfSafe).

Answer (score 1):

According to `ngBindHtmlDirective` you can do it like this:

HTML:

```
<div ng-if="isSafeHtml()">
  <div ng-bind-html="invalidHtml"></div>
</div>
<div ng-if="!isSafeHtml()">
  {{invalidHtml}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.isSafeHtml = function() {
   return !!$sce.getTrustedHtml($scope.invalidHtml);
}
```

Modified plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Besix3PfQ1TjUEEagfca?p=preview

Comment: Interesting idea. That might be good enough to get us past this. Thanks!